# Formdata object shows empty even after calling append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Append in formdata Object shows empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var formy = new FormData();
        formy.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0]);
        console.log(formy);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="file" type="file" size="40"><br><br>
<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of the above code in the console log gives me

```
Formdata{}
append:function append()
arguments:null
caller:null
length:2
name:"append"
```

whereas `console.log($("#file")[0].files[0])` gives me File `{name: "document.pdf", lastModified: 1462959300000, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 11 2016 15:05:00 GMT+0530 (IST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5275…}`

Why is append for formdata not working?

Answer (score 32):

Actually append IS WORKING. But you cannot log that way.
To see your content, try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var formy = new FormData();
        formy.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0]);

    for(var pair of formy.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0]+', '+pair[1]);
    }

});
});
</script>
```

I have added a screenshot of same code with 3 console statements.
First is your files[0] object.
Second is your pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVquK.png).
Third is your form object which will be empty as you are reporting.

Why and how is this happening can be read here. No point in duplicating theory here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

[image: # I have provided description of console statements above]

Answer (score 26):

A easier way to log formData is by using the .get() method.

```
console.log(formy.get("firstname"))
console.log(formy.get("lastname"))
```

As the case maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I think the DOM file attribute has error while appending ,thus unable to identify the file attribute in the DOM causing caller as null exception.
And also FormData() must return a selector that gets intialized.
Try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            //var formy = new FormData(); 
            //formy must return valid DOM selector and since our FormData code is unknown,I am using Div as example
            //formy.append($('input[type="file"]'), $("#file")[0].files[0]); 
            $('#div1').append($('input[type="file"]'), $("#file1")[0].files[0])
//Now no null encountered
//   console.log($('div').append($('input[type="file"]'), $("#file1")[0].files[0]));
    });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="file1" type="file" size="40"><br><br>
        <button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>
        <div id="div1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Because :file is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :file cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="file"] instead.
SRC:jQuery Api documentation

Comment: @KanikaMidha let me know if still you have issues. :)

Comment: I get same issue.