# Why FormData object is empty even after I use append?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, form-data

I tried the following code:
(This is my service file in angular posts.service.ts)

```
 updatePost(id: string, title: string, content: string, image: File | string) {
        let postData: Post | FormData;
        console.log(id);
        if(typeof(image) === 'object'){
            console.log("Image is object");
            const postData = new FormData();
            postData.append('id',id);
            postData.append('title',title);
            postData.append('content', content);
            postData.append('image', image, title);
            console.log(postData)
        } else {
            console.log("In else!")
            postData = { id: id, title: title, content: content, imagePath: image };
        }
```

When I check `console.log(postData)`, it is empty.

Comment: But, if instead of console.logging the whole thing, you `console.log(postData.get('id'))`, you'll see the set value.

Comment: const postData = new FormData; should be const postData = new FormData();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formdata object shows empty even after calling append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235810/formdata-object-shows-empty-even-after-calling-append)