# Bad request status 400 when trying to upload image file to imgur

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, uploading, imgur

I'm trying upload image file from my React app.
Keep getting 400 error, witch I can't understand why.
That's my TypeScript function's code in React:

```
   public setImage = (args: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        const image = args.target.files[0];
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append("profileImage", image, image.name);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Client-ID //my client-id here//' },
            image: image
        };
        fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));

    }
```

**And the error:**

```
{
data: error: "No image data was sent to the upload api"
method: "POST"request: "/3/image"
__proto__: Objectstatus: 400
success: false
__proto__: Object
}
```

When i'm trying to console my FormData object after appending I can see an empty object.
Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to log the image object as well and see if there are any problems there.

Also please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235810/formdata-object-shows-empty-even-after-calling-append) to verify that you're logging your FormData object correctly.

If however, this is still not enough to debug the issue, I would advise you to try rolling a request using something like curl or Fiddler since you are manually creating the POST headers. Because of this, you're not sending the Content-Length header which could cause the imgur api to just skip the whole body of your request.

To get the content lenght you could do something like:

```
    let content-length = JSON.stringify(formData).length;
```

Then simply:

```
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Client-ID //my client-id here//', 'Content-Length': content-length },
        image: image
    };
```

Hope this is useful in some way.