# Sending request with form-data failed, it send an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, form-data

I am trying to use FormData to send user-entered data in a POST request with the fetch API. The problem is when I try to use form-data type, there is no data in the req.body, it’s an empty object. And without using form-data sending a request is totally normal and I have my data stored in req.body as usual.

This is my code:

```js
/*
some code ...
*/

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', formState.inputs.name.value);
formData.append('email', formState.inputs.email.value);
formData.append('password', formState.inputs.password.value);
formData.append('image', formState.inputs.image.value);

const responseData = await fetch(
  "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup",
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  }
);
// it return >>> POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

this is users-controllers file:

```js
/*
some code ...
*/

const signup = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({user: req.body})
}

module.exports = {
  getUsers,
  signup,
  login,
};
```

and this is user-routes file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { body } = require("express-validator");

const { getUsers, signup, login } = require("../controllers/users-controllers");
const fileUpload = require('../middleware/file-upload');

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getUsers);

router.post(
  "/signup",
  fileUpload.single('image'),
  body("name").not().isEmpty(),
  body("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
  body("password").isLength({ min: 6 }),
  signup
);

router.post("/login", login);

module.exports = router;
```

and this is file-upload file:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
}

const fileUpload = multer({
    limits: 500000,
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'uploads/images');
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) =>  {
            const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
            cb(null, uuidv1() + '.' + ext);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        const error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type!');
        cb(error, isValid);
    }
});

module.exports = fileUpload;
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Rather than simply logging `formData`, you can log the content of FormData using the spread operator `console.log(...formData)`

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/37235810/7785337

Comment: Remove the `content-type` header. It is not required and will mess up the server handling of your upload

Comment: @Phil I remove it but I still have the same error

Comment: @AdibHasib why request body is empty when posting form-data?